# Userform input into next empty cell not working

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have setup a Userform that inputs two values into the next available cell in a range. The code for this is:

```
Private Sub BTNSUBMIT_Click ()

Dim I AsLong
Dim X AsLong

Sheets("Sales").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Activate

    Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0)) = False
        I = I + 1
    Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0).Value = CBCLIENTS.Value

Sheets("Sales").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("O3").Activate

    Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0)) = False
        X = X + 1
    Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0).Value = TBTONS.Value
End Sub
```

These work as intended by selecting the next empty cell, writing the client or ton value, and writing future input into the next empty cell. However I tried to use the same code for a checkbox to input a value and it does not work. Instead the checkbox keeps writing on top of the active cell. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CHKTALCUM_Click()

Dim T As Long

Sheets("Sales").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Activate

    Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(T, 0)) = False
        T = T + 1
    Loop

ActiveCell(T, 0).Value = TBTONSCHECK.Value
End Sub
```

I'm at a loss. If anyone can offer up some insight on why the same code line is not working please do not hesitate to reply.

Comment: The best way to get the next empty row is with `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` assuming you'll always have data in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the 'Offset' in the checkbox code

```
ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0).Value = TBTONS.Value
```

compared to

```
ActiveCell(T, 0).Value = TBTONSCHECK.Value
```

Comment: Thank you, Rdster. I think today we learned why it's important to take breaks at work.

Comment: Yup, get up and take a lap. :)